# YAML/Ruby: Get the first item whose <field> is <value>?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have this YAML:

```
- company: 
  - id: toyota
  - fullname: トヨタ自動車株式会社
- company:
  - id: konami
  - fullname: Konami Corporation
```

And I want to get the **fullname of the company whose id is `konami`**.

Using Ruby 1.9.2, what is the simplest/usual way to get it?

*Note: In the rest of my code, I have been using `require "yaml"` so I would prefer to use the same library.*

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: I updated my answer to show that if you change your yaml, it becomes much easier to do what you want.

Comment: @mischa: Great!! That's perfect. I should really take the time to learn more about YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works too and does not use iteration:

```
y = YAML.load_file('japanese_companies.yml')
result = y.select{ |x| x['company'].first['id'] == 'konami' }
result.first['company'].last['fullname'] # => "Konami Corporation"
```

Or if you have other attributes and you can't be sure `fullname` is the last one:

```
result.first['company'].select{ |x| x['fullname'] }.first['fullname']
```

I agree with Ray Toal, if you change your yml it becomes much easier. E.g.:

```
toyota:
  fullname: トヨタ自動車株式会社
konami:
  fullname: Konami Corporation
```

With the above yaml, fetching the fullname of konami becomes much easier:

```
y = YAML.load_file('test.yml')
y.fetch('konami')['fullname']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML is a little unconventional but we can compensate.

A brute force approach is (I'm not sure if this can be done without parsing the YAML):

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.parse_file(ARGV[0]).transform.each do |company|
  properties = {}
  company['company'].each {|h| properties = properties.merge(h)}
  puts properties['fullname'] if properties['id'] == 'konami'
end
```

Pass your YAML file in as the first argument to this script.

Feel free to adapt into a method that takes the YAML as a string and *returns* the desired fullname. (A return is useful because it directly answers the OP's question of obtaining the *first* such company.)

Comment: I am very open to suggestions for a better YAML format :-) Note: Company actually contains other fields and an array of strings

Comment: By unconventional I mean that you don't want hyphens before each of the properties of a company (like id, fullname, etc.).  By having them there, you make them separate objects in an array.  Without those "inner" hyphens the problem becomes much simpler.

Comment: Great trick! I made my YAML simpler, but I will keep the question as is, because people have already posted answers.